# Best way to loop Obj data in HTML document with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm developing a simple SPA framework. I have a problem. I want to render my Obj data in HTML. Below is my code and [my online example](https://simple-singal-app-page.herokuapp.com/test)

```js
var data = {
  for: {
    animal: [{
        name: 'dog',
        alive: 'false'
      },
      {
        name: 'cat',
        alive: 'true'
      }
    ],
    human: [{
        name: 'bob',
        sex: 'male'
      },
      {
        name: 'alice',
        sex: 'female'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

```html
<html>
<div id="app">
  <ol>
    <li np-for="animal">
      <np tag="text-for" data="name"></np><br>
      <np tag="text-for" data="alive"></np>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>

</html>
```

best way to solve it?

Comment: are you using a framework?

Comment: I'm developing a simple SPA framework,this's a problem i encountered .[My framework](https://github.com/zenlykoi/NPjs-Simple-Single-App-Page/blob/master/public/np.js)

Comment: using no frameworks you'll have to create <li> programatically and add to <ul> as a child

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a framework, then I suggest you using jQuery, so the full code looks like this

```js
let data = {
    animals : [
    { name: 'dog', alive : 'false'},
    { name: 'cat', alive : 'true'}
  ]
};

let animalList = $('#animals');
data.animals.forEach(function(data) {
  animalList.append(`<li>
  <b>${data.name}</b>
  <i>${data.alive}</i>
</li>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <div id="app">
    <ul id="animals">
    <!-- data will automatically generated by jQuery -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</html>
```

I suggest you to using `let` or `const` for static variable instead of `var`, read more [var vs let vs const in JavaScript](https://tylermcginnis.com/var-let-const/)

Read more about [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Thank u, but that's not what i want, you can see [my online example](https://simple-singal-app-page.herokuapp.com/test)